# image segmentation by k means clustering in python

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, cluster-analysis

I have been trying to figure out how to segment an image by K-means clustering in Python modules like skimage or scipy. I found a code [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_lena_segmentation.html)

When I try to run the code for my image, my python interpreter stops responding.

Also I don't understand the downsampling part of the code in the above given link.
Please tell me how to do it?

Comment: Study and understand the code, instead of blindly running it. In particular, pay attention to scalability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is correct, (it work fine for me). It just take time, to finish (80 second on my laptop). Maybe you need a image in grayscale like lena image.

For the downsampling;

```
lena = sp.misc.lena()
print np.shape(lena)
print np.shape(lena[::2, ::2])   # lena[0,0], lena[0,2], lena[0,4], lena[0,6]
print np.shape(lena[1::2, ::2])  # lena[1,0], lena[1,2], lena[1,4], lena[1,6]
print np.shape(lena[::2, 1::2])  # lena[0,1], lena[0,3], lena[0,5], lena[0,7]
print np.shape(lena[1::2, 1::2]) # lena[1,1], lena[1,3], lena[1,5], lena[1,7]

# lena[0,0], lena[0,2], lena[0,4], lena[0,6], ...
#   +      ,   +      ,   +      ,   +      ,  +
# lena[1,0], lena[1,2], lena[1,4], lena[1,6], ...
#   +      ,   +      ,   +      ,   +      ,  +
# lena[0,1], lena[0,3], lena[0,5], lena[0,7], ...
#   +      ,   +      ,   +      ,   +      ,  +
# lena[1,1], lena[1,3], lena[1,5], lena[1,7], ...
#   =      ,   =      ,   =      ,   =      ,  =
# lena[0,0], lena[0,1], lena[0,2], lena[0,3], ...


lena = lena[::2, ::2] + lena[1::2, ::2] + lena[::2, 1::2] + lena[1::2, 1::2]
print 'Shape :', np.shape(lena)
lena = lena[::2, ::2] + lena[1::2, ::2] + lena[::2, 1::2] + lena[1::2, 1::2]
print 'Shape :', np.shape(lena)
```

Comment: I tried to downsample with this code and get the following output and error for my image: output : (1571L, 1571L)
(786L, 786L)
(785L, 786L)
(786L, 785L)
(785L, 785L) and error: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (786,786) (785,786)

Comment: Hi, with this code, you need a image with pair shape.

Crop you image like this : image = image[0:1570, 0:1570]